# Yii Application Migrating From Windows To Linux Platform

Tags: yii, frameworks

We have developed a project with Yii framework on local windows server. It is working with no problem on a local windows server.But when we uploaded the project to a linux hosting it started giving us problems. Not getting where is an issue?

Comment: A description of the issues would go a long way to help people understand your problem...That said, the major issues I experience while deploying ( I develop on Windows and deploy on Linux servers) has to do with file and folder permissions and file system naming conventions... If these are your problems, then it's easily solveable

Answer (score 0):

Linux accesses files (and therefore all classes it autoloads) case-sensitively. You may run into problems when your models are called something like Contractperiod and accessing them like ContractPeriod. Rename their files to use the same name as their classes (.php) and any code using those classes to use the right names to fix this kind of issue.

Then there's the permissions; your runtime and assets folders need write access under Linux. Windows needs this as well but usually gets it automatically by being ran under an administrator account (unless you've properly configured your Windows web server). See chmod.

You may experience issues due to different PHP versions as some Linux distributions such as Debian don't have updated PHP versions in their default packages. Another possibility is that your PHP is configured differently on your Linux server; showing errors that are hidden on Windows. Generally these should be solved by repairing the code.

To get a more specific answer (or guess) for your instance you're going to have to provide us with more information, such as a copy of some of the errors.